# Navigation from weblink to ionic app

Tags: cordova

I want to open mobile app in ios version above 9 from weblink using ionic.
 I have used below plugin for the process 
"cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-customurlscheme --variable URL_SCHEME=eventley".
It is working fine in android and below version of ios 9.
I have created apple-app-site-association and uploaded in root directory of web server also for ios.
Please give me the best solution for it. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using this ionic plugin? https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-deeplinks

Comment: Yes, i tried above plugin,after adding plugin i got below errors.         ionic-plugin-deeplinks is not set in the config.xml. The plugin's entitlement generation is not going to work.

No host is specified in the config.xml. Ionic Deeplinks Plugin entitlement generation is not going to work.

Comment: could you try creating a new blank project and try adding the library to that and test it. probably there are issues with your code. So have a fresh start and test the library in that. If it works in the blank project, then there are issues in your code. :)